# Why NextJS API route can't fetch to Microsoft Azure Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, azure, next.js

When I try to fetch ... , I get an error. The url and port are correct, when I open the url in browser it works fine and gives me response, but when I try to connect to it from API route all breaks.

Error itself

> TypeError: fetch failed
>
> at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14062:11)
>
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
>
> { cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:7071
>
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)      at
>
> TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
>
> errno: -4078,
>
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>
> syscall: 'connect',
>
> address: '::1',
>
> port: 7071   } }

API route

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
    try {
        // Connect to mcrft azure func endpoint
        const response = await fetch(
            `${process.env.VERCEL_URL || "http://localhost:7071"
            }/api/getChatGPTSuggestion`,
            {
                cache: "no-store",
            }
        );

        const textData = await response.text();

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(textData.trim()), {
            status: 200,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error inside get route", error)
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            return new Response(error.message, { status: 500 });
        }

        return new Response("Internal Server Error", { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

Cloud function

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions')
const openai = require('../../lib/openai')

app.http('getChatGPTSuggestion', {
  methods: ['GET'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt:
        '...',
      max_tokens: 100, 
      temperature: 0.8,
    })

    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`)

    const responseText = response.data.choices[0].text

    return {
      body: responseText,
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The *address: '::1'* in your error message indicates it's trying to connect to localhost.

> The ipv6 localhost address is 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 , which can be abbreviated to ::1

process.env.VERCEL_URL is probably not set correctly.

Comment: process.env.VERCEL_URL is a system var which will be not undefined when I deploy my project, but now I connect only to localhost, it is like it needs to work, but I don't really undestand why I can't connect to localhost.

Comment: Are you facing the error locally or on the hosted environment?

Comment: I face the error locally.